# Trying to create a chat application using sockets in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, sockets, django-templates

I am creating chat application using django to create a chat app , that will help to establish a chat between user and admin.I have a code written in python that will help to communicate through the terminal , but i am not able to find out the solution , how i attach to frontend eg html, css.

server.py

```
# server.py

def do_some_stuffs_with_input(input_string):  
    """
    This is where all the processing happens.

    Let's just read the string backwards
    """

    print("Processing that nasty input!")
    return input_string[::-1]

def client_thread(conn, ip, port, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096):

    # the input is in bytes, so decode it

    input_from_client_bytes = conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)

    # MAX_BUFFER_SIZE is how big the message can be
    # this is test if it's sufficiently big
    import sys
    siz = sys.getsizeof(input_from_client_bytes)
    if  siz >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE:
        print("The length of input is probably too long: {}".format(siz))

    # decode input and strip the end of line
    input_from_client = input_from_client_bytes.decode("utf8").rstrip()

    res = do_some_stuffs_with_input(input_from_client)
    print("Result of processing {} is: {}".format(input_from_client, res))

    vysl = res.encode("utf8")  # encode the result string
    conn.sendall(vysl)  # send it to client
    conn.close()  # close connection
    print('Connection ' + ip + ':' + port + " ended")
import time, socket, sys


print("\nWelcome to Chat Room\n")
print("Initialising....\n")
time.sleep(1)

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
port = 1234
s.bind((host, port))
print(host, "(", ip, ")\n")
name = input(str("Enter your name: "))

s.listen(1)
print("\nWaiting for incoming connections...\n")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Received connection from ", addr[0], "(", addr[1], ")\n")

s_name = conn.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print(s_name, "has connected to the chat room\nEnter [e] to exit chat room\n")
conn.send(name.encode())

while True:
    message = input(str("Me : "))
    if message == "[e]":
        message = "Left chat room!"
        conn.send(message.encode())
        print("\n")
        break
    conn.send(message.encode())
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(s_name, ":", message)
```

client.py

```
# client.py
import time, socket, sys

print("\nWelcome to Chat Room\n")
print("Initialising....\n")
time.sleep(1)

s = socket.socket()
shost = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(shost)
print(shost, "(", ip, ")\n")
host = input(str("Enter server address: "))
name = input(str("\nEnter your name: "))
port = 1234
print("\nTrying to connect to ", host, "(", port, ")\n")
time.sleep(1)
s.connect((host, port))
print("Connected...\n")

s.send(name.encode())
s_name = s.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print(s_name, "has joined the chat room\nEnter [e] to exit chat room\n")

while True:
    message = s.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(s_name, ":", message)
    message = input(str("Me : "))
    if message == "[e]":
        message = "Left chat room!"
        s.send(message.encode())
        print("\n")
        break
    s.send(message.encode())
```

Comment: Have some done this before.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial - this tutorial is about developing a chat app using django and vue.js.

https://danidee10.github.io/2018/01/01/realtime-django-1.html

Connection with other frameworks like react or angular is similar. Just checkout the tutorial. Hope it helps you.